# Does $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}(\sup_{x \in [0, 1]}f_{n}(x)) < \infty$ imply $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}f_{n}(x)$ converges uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $\{f_{n}\}$ be a sequence of functions on $[0, 1]$ such that $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}(\sup_{x \in [0, 1]}f_{n}(x)) < \infty$ and $\sup_{x \in [0, 1]}f_{n}(x) \geq 0$. Must $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}f_{n}(x)$ converge uniformly?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(x)$ need not even converge, do you mean $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f_n(x)|)<\infty$?

Comment: @neth: If $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}(\sup_{x \in [0, 1]}|f_{n}(x)| < \infty$, then does $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}f_{n}(x)$ converges uniformly by the Weierstrass M-test?

Comment: @ADF Yes, what you ask in your comment is correct (this IS Weierstrass' M-test says).

Answer (score 2):

No. Take 
$$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
-1/n & \mbox{ if } x = 0 \\
1/n^2 & \mbox{ if } x = 1 \\
0 & \mbox{ if } x\in (0,1).
\end{cases}
$$
Then $\sup_{x \in [0,1]} f_n(x) = 1/n^2 \geq 0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sup_{x \in [0,1]} f_n(x) < \infty$ (by the $p$-test; in fact it's $\pi^2/6$, c.f., [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem)). However, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ does not converge uniformly; it diverges at 0.